# Why am I getting "Invalid hook call" in react monorepo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, metro-bundler

### Intro

I've a react monorepo, managed with `lerna` and `yarn workspace`, and there are 3 packages inside:

- React Native application for iOS and Android with customized Metro bundler
- Web application created with CRA 5 with customized webpack config by using CRACO
- Common: are common functions, logic and custom hooks to share the logic between the RN app and the webapp

In the common package, before start testing, I had only modules that containing types and I had installed thos as dev dependencies. **With this configuration everything was working**, the web and mobile app starts without errors.

---

### Problem

Problems arrived when I wanted to test custom hooks in the common package (for test the shared logic). I've runned jest (already used to test some classes and unit testing some pure functions) and it correctly spit off an error that said that it cannot find react module. That's correct because I installed just @types/react and react was a peerDependency.

After install React in the common package as a devDependency, Jest work as intended, but the mobile app and the web app saying the same thing:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

The thing that I don't get is **why am I getting this error**??
I've already use `nohoist` option on react and react native with this config:

```json
{
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**",
      "**/react",
      "**/react/**"
    ]
  },
}
```

I've this configuration in the root `package.json`.

This is my `metro.config.js` used by React Native:

```js
const path = require('path');
const Resolver = require('metro-resolver');

const watchFolders = [
  //Relative path to packages directory
  path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  path.join(__dirname, '..', 'common'),
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'node_modules'),
];

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    // This was added to enable Metro to handle the symlinks that yarn
    // workspaces places in the node_modules folder.
    extraNodeModules: new Proxy(
      {},
      {
        get: (target, name) => {
          return path.join(__dirname, `node_modules/${name}`);
        },
      },
    ),
    // Make sure we use the local copy of react and react-native
    resolveRequest: (context, realModuleName, platform, moduleName) => {
      const clearContext = { ...context, resolveRequest: undefined };
      const module =
        moduleName === 'react' || moduleName === 'react-native'
          ? path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', realModuleName)
          : realModuleName;
      return Resolver.resolve(clearContext, module, platform);
    },
  },
  watchFolders,
};
```

and this is my `craco.config.js` use by the CRA web project:

```js
const path = require('path');
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require('@craco/craco');
const { CracoAliasPlugin } = require('react-app-alias');

const packages = [];
packages.push(path.join(__dirname, '../common'));

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, arg) => {
      const { isFound, match } = getLoader(
        webpackConfig,
        loaderByName('babel-loader'),
      );
      if (isFound) {
        const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include)
          ? match.loader.include
          : [match.loader.include];

        match.loader.include = include.concat(packages);
      }

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {
        alias: {
          react: './node_modules/react',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I don't understand why both bundlers are getting the wrong modules, I'm already use alias and resolver in the correct way to avoid this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show where you are using your hooks please ?

Comment: Hooks are defined in the common package, and imported in the mobile and web packages. Everything was working fine before install `react` lib as a dev dependency of the common package.

Comment: Your hook still can not be defined outside a React component, even if they are called inside a component